# fontello CSS works on local machine but not once uploaded to server

Tags: html, css, fontello

I am using `fontello.css` in my web site. It works fine on my computer and in all browsers, no problem at all. But when I upload it to server it is not working properly.

The `fontello.css` is located in:`Styles/css/fontello/css/fontello.css`.
here is my code:

```
<link href="Styles/css/fontello/css/fontello.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<p class="scrolldown">
    <a class="smoothscroll" href=""><i class="icon-down-circle"></i></a>
</p>
```

Comment: Try using a full path URL and check.

Comment: i am looking for link to online fontello.css in my site. but i can not find it's address that replace in href.

Comment: sorry does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Relative path can cause problems on some servers while it's working on localhost without a problem. Try using full path,not relative. If the css file is located in `http://www.example.com/Styles/css/fontello/css/fontello.css` use `<link href="http://www.example.com/Styles/css/fontello/css/fontello.css" rel="stylesheet" />` as path. In that way your css will be correct on any page

Comment: i used full path exactly.but still it's not working.

Comment: Check your structure. Font must be in the same directory as css. If this is case, try setting full path in `fontello.css` like `src: url('../font/fontello.eot?85817989');` change to `src: url('http://www.example.com/Styles/font/fontello.eot?85817989');` and do that for each line that use relative path

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem where my fontello icons were either not showing or they were displaying the wrong icons.

I was using Cloudfare on the site so I purged the cache of all pages and the icons worked fine.

So if you are using cloud fare be sure to purge cache.

Hope this helps, sorry if not!